# SQL query for "Classification Set" formatted CSV export

Tags: sql, sqlite, hierarchical-data

I'm working on a project where I need to create a specifically formatted CSV file for import into another application. The format defines a "Classification Set" that is used to build a drill down lookup list, based on the values in the columns (see screenshot of the CSV file below). These are a pain to create, so I'd like to setup a SQLite database with tables of the values and an SQL query, which creates a view that can be exported into the format below.

What is the best, most efficient way to accomplish this? Should I have a single table with fields for Kingdom, Class, Species, etc. with the values filled in for everything or separate tables and some kind of distinct join with grouping? An example query would be helpful to get me going.

[image: Classification Set]

Comment: Do you have SQLite 3.8.3, so that you could use [recursive common table expressions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a ROLLUP query in  SQL but I do not think SQLite supports it. ROLLUP query can be implemented as UNION query, ROLLUP is just little  more efficient than UNION :

```
SELECT A, NULL, NULL ... 
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL, B, NULL ... 
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL, NULL, C ...
```

Comment: How would you get these A,B,C values from the table?

Comment: I do not see your tables, but I would use three related tables : Kingdom -> Class -> Species with  NAME and PARENT_NAME fields to join them on PARENT_NAME. A,B,C is simply a NAME fields from this hierarchy tables.

Comment: It is fine to de normalize as single table if you need it as an intermediate result. De normalized model will be single table  and A,B,C will be Kingdom_Name, Class_Name,  Species_Name

Comment: `SELECT name, NULL, NULL FROM kingdom
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, c.name, NULL FROM class c
LEFT JOIN kingdom k ON k.name = c.parent_name
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, s.name FROM species s
LEFT JOIN class c ON c.name = s.parent_name
`

Not quite there yet...